# Is there a locally finite tree having every other locally finite tree as a subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, infinite-graphs

Is there a locally finite tree $T$ such that any locally finite tree is isomorphic to a subgraph of $T$?

Comment: This appears to be a problem from a still-open competition (https://upper.school/).